# Why using the address of the first element of the array as template non-type argument is possible in c++ 17

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, language-lawyer, non-type-template-parameter

```cpp
template<typename T, T nontype_param>
class C {};

int a[10];
C<int *, &a[0]> err3;
```

The code above will throw an error when the standard of c++ is lower than 17, while it will be ok when the standard is 17. Could someone explain the reasons to me?

According the information on the [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters):

> The only exceptions are that non-type template parameters of reference or pointer type and non-static data members of reference or pointer type in a non-type template parameter of class type and its subobjects(since C++20) cannot refer to/be the address of

> or a subobject (including non-static class member, base subobject, or array element) of one of the above(since C++20).

(The words in cppreference are formatted, and I am unsure how to correctly paste it here in markdown. If you are confused by my reference, please click the link and find the section to read. )

I think using the address of the first element of the array as template non-type argument should not pass even in c++ 17.

Comment: What compiler? It doesn't pass in GCC: https://godbolt.org/z/szco4cT7G

Comment: @paddy [compiles with all compilers in c++20](https://godbolt.org/z/n7EzTYfdG)

Comment: @paddy Thank you for your comment. After seeing your comment, I retry the code, it exactly doesn't pass. I think the IDE syntax error highlighting should blame for my question. The IDE I am using didn't give me error highlighting while I am using c++ 17.

Comment: In C++20 the program is well-formed due to [temp.arg](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg#nontype-6.5) but in C++17 it is ill-formed as per [temp.arg](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.arg#nontype-2.1) as explained in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78024505/12002570).

Comment: Basically c++20 removed the restriction that address of any subobject cannot be used a template argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tldr;**

The answer depends on which standard c++ version you're using as explained below. In C++20 the program is **well-formed** while in C++17 it is **ill-formed**. The important thing to note is that `a` has [static storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/static_storage_duration) and that c++20 allows the address of  [*certain subobjects*](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg#nontype-6.5)(as opposed to C++17 which didn't allow "any" subobject address) to be template arguments.

##### C++20

The program is **well-formed** in c++20 as per [temp.arg.nontype](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg#nontype-6):

> **For a non-type template-parameter of** reference or **pointer type**, or for each non-static data member of reference
> or pointer type in a non-type template-parameter of class type or subobject thereof, the reference or **pointer
> value shall not** refer to or **be the address of** (respectively):
>
> - a temporary object
> - a string literal object
> - the result of a `typeid` expression
> - a predefined **func** variable or
> - *a subobject (6.7.2) of one of the above*.

(emphasis mine)

Since `&a[0]` is neither of the above things mentioned in the list, the program is **well-formed**.

Also note that the template argument must be a **converted constant expression** which is true here. From [temp.arg](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.arg#nontype-2):

> **A template-argument for a non-type template-parameter shall be a converted constant expression** ([expr.const]) of the type of the template-parameter.
> [ Note: If the template-argument is an overload set (or the address of such, including forming a pointer-to-member), the matching function is selected from the set ([over.over]).
> — end note
> ]

Note a converted constant expression should also be a constant expression as per [expr.const](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.const#10):

> A converted constant expression of type T is an expression, implicitly converted to type T, **where the converted expression is a constant expression** and the implicit conversion sequence contains only :
> *
> ...

Now we move onto [constant expression](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.const#11)

> A constant expression is either a glvalue core constant expression that refers to an entity that is a permitted result of a constant expression (as defined below), or a prvalue core constant expression whose value satisfies the following constraints:
>
> - **if the value is of pointer type, it contains the address of an object with static storage duration**, the address past the end of such an object ([expr.add]), the address of a non-immediate function, or a null pointer value,

---

##### C++17

In C++17, the program is **ill-formed** as per [temp.arg](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.arg#nontype-2):

> A template-argument for a non-type template-parameter shall be a converted constant expression of the type of the template-parameter. **For a non-type template-parameter of** reference or **pointer type**, **the value of the constant expression shall not** refer to (or for a pointer type, shall not **be the address of**):
>
> - a **subobject**,

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Excuse me, could you please explain the situation in C++20 in simpler terms? It's easy to understand what will happen in C++17, and I know that `a` has static storage duration. However, I didn't quite grasp the point that c++20 allows the address of certain subobjects to be template arguments. What is a certain subobject? And the the hyperlink on the certain subobject seems to link the wrong part.

Comment: `shall not refer to or be the address of (respectively)` means `shall not refer to or shall not be the address of` or `shall not refer to or can be the address of`  ? I think the expression seems to be ambiguous.  (Or it may be difficult for non-native English speaker to understand. )

Comment: @fade this is what it is. The C++ standard has to be very precise in its wording (i am not saying it is easy to read). I think your main confusion is about the word"object". An object in the standard is not (only) an instance of a class. It can also be things like an int, and array or as I like to think of it : "anything that has a lifetime".

Comment: @fade Sure. If you refer to [intro.object](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#2.sentence-2), you'll note that an array element is also called a *subobject*. So `&a[0]` is neither a temporary object, a string literal object, the result of typeid expression, a predefined func and lastly it is neither a suboject of any of the above. So it can be used as a non type template argument(also note that it has to satisfy another requirements like being a converted constant expression etc )

Comment: @fade The two things to note here are 1) `a` has static storage duration and 2) c++17 used to say "subobject" but c++20 changed it to "subobject of one of the above". Btw I'm also a non-native speaker, and the wording here seems clear enough to me.

Comment: @PepijnKramer @user12002570 Thank you for your response. However, I am still unclear about the issue. In C++17, the error occurs because `&a[0]` represents the address of a subobject `a[0]`. Nevertheless, there seems to be a limitation in C++20, which states that "the reference or pointer value shall not refer to or be the address of (respectively): a subobject (6.7.2) of one of the above". Does this mean that the pointer value can be the address of a subobject such as an array element?

Comment: @fade The pointer value `&a[0]` is not the address of a subobject of either of those things(a temporary object, string literal object, typeid expression and predefined func variable). So `&a[0]` can be a template nontype argument.

Comment: @user12002570 I read it again, I think I hava got your point. Yes, it is what it is. Thank you.

Comment: @fade *"I read it again, I think I hava got your point...."* Yeah rereading it makes it clear as it once did for me too.